# Round images for map pins

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am having trouble with Google Map Markers. I am wanting to have a round image as the pin for the map. After looking around, it seems like it is not possible. So i'm wondering if i could maybe change what i have below (which works for placing square images on the map) and crop the image *before* giving it to the iconimage object? So I take the image, cut it to shape, then place it as the iconimage.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

```
angular.forEach(data, function(data){


    var iconimage = {
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+data.facebookid+"/picture?type=small",
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        optimized: false
    };


    var friendPin = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.location.latitude,data.location.longitude),
        map: googleMap.map,
        icon: iconimage,
    });

    friendPin.setMap(googleMap.map);


});
```

Comment: You need round markers.  Do you have a server available, where you can generate round images comming from another server (facebook)?  I don't see how this can be done just with javascript (maybe it is possible).

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay At the moment, the images come directly from Facebook. As its all done in real time. So i cannot really take the images and send them to a server for processing before returning them. Maybe i can request round images from Facebook?